# \textbf does not work with cmvtt style

Tags: fonts, bold

I am using

`\renewcommand*\ttdefault{cmvtt}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}`

in order to get typewriting style. However, I notice that, `\textbf` does not work? There is no error or warning. I just see that the font of the text is still the same without any changing.

Any help please?

Comment: This means that your `cmvtt` most likely does not have a bold version of `tt`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thank you so much for your help. How could I solve the problem?

Comment: Probably, nobody has designed a matching bold version. It is not available. There is no bold for `cmvtt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Latin Modern fonts (kind of successor of the Computer Modern fonts) have bold variants for the type writer families:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}% use lmvtt instead of lmtt for \ttfamily
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}

\begin{document}
Lorem \textbf{ipsum} \textsl{dolor} \textbf{\textsl{sit}} amur.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you so, so much for your great help. Thank you for all the people in this site. All the best.

Comment: Is it possible to make it look a bit bolder? I've followed the answer to this question but its still quite difficult to distinguish bold text.

Comment: @slew123 There is not much place for thicker letters without increasing the monospace letter width. You can experiment with package `pdfrender` to fill and stroke the letters with an additional stroke width.