# Need help with font and siunitx issue?

Tags: fonts, siunitx

I don't really understand anything about fonts, as much as I have tried to read about them. I ultimately just wanted a font that kinda looked like it was written in a typewriter style, which also had clear math symbols to read. I found an example somewhere here on the stackexchange (see link below), used pdflatex to compile it, I thought it looked ok. But some of the math fonts, when using `siunitx` look squashed in the inline math mode.

My minimum working example is this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{book}

\usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}  % line 2  
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault} % line 3
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
    detect-all = true,
    detect-inline-family = text,
    detect-inline-weight = text
}

\begin{document}

\noindent normal text: [\SI{5}{\milli\meter\squared}] \\ 
inline math mode: $[\SI{5}{\milli\meter\squared}]$ \\
mm 

\end{document}
```

If I just use the default fonts, i.e. remove line 2 and 3, then use siunitx, the "mm" looks like the same font as the text.

Can anyone help me prevent the text getting squashed like this, or suggest an alternative font that won't have this issue?

Link: 
[\textbf does not work with cmvtt style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415914/textbf-does-not-work-with-cmvtt-style/415936?noredirect=1#comment1133482_415936)

EDIT: I edited the MWE with \sisetup but was not able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to turn off automatic detection of the mode, and specify `siunitx` to always use text mode, which will use `\texttt` instead of `\mathtt` (which is the squished up one).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{book}

\usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}  % line 2  
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault} % line 3
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
    detect-mode=false,
    mode=text,
}

\begin{document}

    \noindent 
    normal text: [\SI{5}{\milli\meter\squared}] \\ 
    inline math mode: $[\SI{5}{\milli\meter\squared}]$ \\
    mm \\
    $\mathtt{mm}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can re-declare the `\mathtt`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{book}

\usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}  % line 2  
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault} % line 3
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
    detect-all = true,
    detect-inline-family = text,
    detect-inline-weight = text
}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{OT1}{lmvtt}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{bold}{OT1}{lmvtt}{b}{n}

\begin{document}

\noindent normal text: [\SI{5}{\milli\meter\squared}] \\ 
inline math mode: $[\SI{5}{\milli\meter\squared}]$ \\
mm 

\noindent
{\boldmath mathtt in bold math: $\mathtt{mm}$}% testing
```

\end{document}

[image]

---

That we need to correct `\mathtt`  is arguably a bug of `lmodern.sty`:  it offers an option `variablett` which switches to `lmvtt` as typewriter font in place of `lmtt` but it still defines `\mathtt` to use `lmtt` because the declaration does not use `\ttdefault`.

If we look at alternative `newtxtext/newtxtt/newtxmath` we see that `newtxmath` does use `\ttdefault` in its declaration of `\mathtt`.

So the following works as expected:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[nomono, ttdefault]{newtxtt}% tt with variable stretch/shrink
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
    detect-all = true,
    detect-inline-family = text,
    detect-inline-weight = text
}

\begin{document}
\noindent normal text: [\SI{5}{\milli\meter\squared}] \\ 
inline math mode: $[\SI{5}{\milli\meter\squared}]$ \\
mm 

\noindent
{\boldmath mathtt in bold math: $\mathtt{mm}$}% testing

\end{document}
```

[image]

<sub>On the other hand the `ttzdefault` option of `newtxtt` does not redefine  `\ttdefault`, so we would still need a `\let\ttdefault\ttzdefault` before loading `newtxmath` then. Anyway, the `nomono, ttdefault` options did the job.</sub>

And the typewriter font will allow hyphenation and text justification.

This is similar to the `lmodern` "variablett" but `lmodern` additionally has variable lengths glyphs (each among a..z has its own width), its `m` in `lmvtt` is not squeezed contrarily to the one from `newtxtt` package even with `nomono` option.

Comment: Yeah I am confused about mathtt. Does it only change inline math font? I haven't used it anywhere so what should I do? I normally just do `$a + b$` etc or use an `equation` environment. The font packages I've used in my report are the ones I gave in the MWE. Is this the correct practice?

Comment: This problem arises only in siunitx context: it appears in math mode, with the options you passed, it uses `\mathtt`. After loading `lmodern` this `\mathtt` will use `lmtt`, i.e. the normal monospaced lmodern font. But you loaded `lmodern` with option `variablett`, so for `\mathtt` to match the actual "tt" font, we need to correct it to use `lmvtt` where `v` stands for variable. It is arguably a bug of `lmodern` package, because as you discovered the `m` glyph looks quite different in the two fonts. You may *try* to report to `lmodern` auth. (I did some other bug report years ago to no avail).